# heroku mongo typeerror Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Any luck with this error anyone.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

This is the error message on Heroku logs. The code runs perfectly locally with a mongo db atlas link but am getting a few issues on the deploying.

Comment: I'm afraid "I have an error, what's the fix?" is somewhat insufficient to resolve your problem.

Comment: Any help you might be willing to offer.

Comment: OK so, in return, I have a question for you. This morning, my car had a problem. There was a weird noise somewhere. Now can you give me the exact fix? How can I repair my car exactly? I need precise instructions. Thanks